# how to generate text boxes dynamicaly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a hrms project in which I have to make the program for time sheet.

I need to take starting date and ending date from the user and depending on the difference of the two dates i have to generate textboxes fro entering time dynamically.that too in the specified place.

can anybody help me out.

Comment: take look at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515

Comment: check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1152363.aspx and http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something very similar to that. Basically, I create a HTML table and create as many columns as needed and create a TextBox in each of those columns like this:

```
myColumn.InnerHtml = "<table>";
        int length = THE NUMBER OF TEXTBOXES YOU WANT TO ADD BASED ON THE DATES;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= length)
        {
            myColumn.InnerHtml += "<tr>";
            myColumn.InnerHtml += "<td><input id='whatever" + i.ToString() + "' type='text' runat='server'></td>";
            unavailableColumn.InnerHtml += "</tr>";
            i++;
        }
        unavailableColumn.InnerHtml += "</table>";
```

myColumn is declared in the aspx like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="myColumn" runat="server" visible="false" style="width: 35%; vertical-align: top">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This code should be added when you have entered the two dates, in order to create the textboxes dynamically. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

a) Take a postback with entered values, and generate new textboxes in CreateChildControls, depending on the values

or

b) Add them with JavaScript and take their values from Request manually.